# How to clean split very large enums in Java

Tags: java, enums, compiler-errors

**tl;dr**

I have an enum class of 10 000 entry that's throw a compiler error because it's too large. I don't know **how to split this huge enum** without doing many enum files.
I don't want t go back to String literal use neither file parsing (see this solution in other post but I really don't found that "clean code")
What could be a good, clean solution ?

**Detailed description**

We have a table with an column A that contains a fix delimited number of string value for each row, it's kind of the primary key. We after referred in the code to this string all the times of this column A to request on the other column of the table. That's why I wanted to use an enum that contains all this key instead of writing a string literal. But there is more than 10 000 entries so the compiler throw an error.
If i do several enum it will be messy because dev will not know which one contains the string they want to use.

I read many times if I'm at this point it means something is wrong with the model, but I don't see what's wrong in: < wanted to use enum instead of string literal everywhere that we don't know what they means.

[for my defense it's the way it works]
There is the table T1 that contains column A: a string, column B: a sql condition, col C: that table on which it's applied.
Then in the code we request on other table and the database API allow you to give only this string (T1.A) and will applied automatically the related condition associated to described table.
So the dev only write *get(String)* and the db will on his own search the condition associated in T1 and applied to the corresponding table T2 for example and return the result.
they can also write *get(string table name)* and get the table with the API.
so the PAIN for me is we have *get(string)* everywhere and we do NOT KNOW if they request a table directly or if they request through the table T1 that represents a SQL condition in fact. The SQL conditions can change through the time exceution dynamically also.
So that's why i wanted to use to have

```
get(CONDTIONS.TOTO) \\ when we request to this T1 table that will use a sql condition to request on another table. in this case CONDITIONS is the enum
```

or

```
get(TABLE.TABLE_MY_NAME) \\ when we request directly to a table using it s name
```

Comment: Enum or not, I think having to code statically against strings/text like that is definitely a (strong) code smell. Unless you use indexes with those strings (like `val1`, `val2`, `val9999`, etc.), I don't see how you can practically use this enum statically. So you can definitely make this enumeration dynamic.

Comment: Do not go with the ENUM/String based solution. Make a master mapping table (like Constant-mapping-master) or an external properties file or cache +Db based solution  and load entries in the table to a hashmap when application startup. Two reason for this approach are (1) this is dynamic and scalable and (2) you can query based on join at db level , never need to read and refer value in code or nested query.

Comment: What is this enum? Instead of an enum, perhaps it's best if you have a class that turns this into an encoded number and back again.

Comment: @ernest_k : so using a external file but i feel like i'm losing my point because it actually proper store in db so it means extracting to a file that s is read after during execution but add regular job schedulor to maintain accurate the file with the database

Comment: @Neil :   i add more explication to the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion:
Rather saving 10k enum in an application
store them in-memory cache server/cluster like redis, nginx (category wise, if possible)